# Showing that $f^{-1}$ has $f_{*}$ as left adjoint.

Tags: category-theory

Here are some of my notes showing $f_{*}$ is left adjoint to $f^{-1}$.

> If we consider the category of subsets $Sub(S)$ of a set $S$, which is the corresponding category of the partial ordered set $(\mathcal{P},\subseteq)$. A function $f: S \to T$ leads to two functors $f^{-1}: Sub(T) \to Sub(S)$ and $f_{*}:Sub(S) \to Sub(T)$. It turns out that $f_{*}$ is left adjoint to $f^{-1}$.  Observing that $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f_{*}(A))$ for all $A$, we don't need to specify the unit of the adjunction. It suffices to check then that $A \subseteq f^{-1}(B) \iff f_{*}(A) \subseteq B$.

I have a doubt. Is it not sufficient to prove $A \subseteq f^{-1}(B) \implies f_{*}(A) \subseteq B$ if one knows that the unit and counit formulation of an adjunction are equivalent?

Comment: Could you please expand on why you think that one direction is sufficient?

Comment: @G.Chiusole because of the definition of adjunction I have (that of Barr and Wells 13.2.1 http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf) which says that for each morphism $f$ there is a unique morphism $g$. Since in this context morphisms are inclusion I just see the need to prove that one inclusion implies the other (inclusions as morphisms are unique).

Comment: Define $f_!(A)=\emptyset$ for all set $A$. You have $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B)\Rightarrow f_!(A)\subseteq B$ (this implication is vacuously true). But the converse does not hold for every sets $A$ and $B$. In other words, if you know only a single implication, the converse may not hold, and in this case $(f^{-1},f_!)$ are not adjoint.

Comment: @Roland This is a good example for when we would only consider that implication, but I think OP means that the implication should be considered in conjunction with $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f_*(A))$, in which case it does work out.

Comment: @MarkKamsma When I first read the OP, I initially thought the unit and counit was established. But when I read it again, it didn't seem obvious at all. So this is a counter-example without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we would prove
$$
A \subseteq f^{-1}(B) \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad f_*(A) \subseteq B, \tag{1}
$$
then this would already prove that it is an adjunction of posets, since this correspondence is automatically natural. So that means there is no need to prove anything about a (co)unit.

Going for the unit approach, it would indeed also be enough to prove $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f_*(A))$ and $A \subseteq f^{-1}(B) \implies f_*(A) \subseteq B$. This works via the general machinery as you mentioned in the comment below your question. Alternatively, we can just prove $(1)$. The forward direction we have already. For the other direction, assume $f_*(A) \subseteq B$. Then $f^{-1}(f_*(A)) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$, and so $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f_*(A)) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$ as required.